# Html.EditorFor Global Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any way to define a global template for the Html.EditorFor helper?

I would like to alter the markup that is output so that for example instead of rendering

```
<div class="editor-label">
  <label .../>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <input .../>
</div>
```

It would render:

```
<div>
    <div class="label"><label..../></div>
    <div class="field"><input..../></div>
</div>
```

This is for when I'm using Html.EditorFor with an object instance not just an object property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Brad Wilson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554/brad-wilson) has written a [**blog series**](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) on asp.net mvc 2 templates. [**This one**](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) is related to your problem.